# Handling Users with MongoDB Stitch App within Atlas Cluster

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch, mongodb-cluster

I have an MongoDB Stitch app, that users the Email/Password authentication. This creates users within the Stitch App that I can authenticate on the page. I also have an MongoDB Atlas Cluster for my database. In the cluster I have a DB with the name of the project, then a collection underneath that for 'Matches'. So when I insert the 'Matches' into the collection, I can send the authenticated user id from Stitch, so that I have a way to query all Matches for a particular User. But how can I add additional values to the 'User' collection in stitch? That user section is sort of prepackaged in Stitch with whatever authentication type you choose (email/password). But for my app I want to be able to store something like a 'MatchesWon' or 'GamePreference' field on the 'User' collection.

Should I create a collection for 'Users' the same way I did for 'Matches' in my Cluster and just insert the user id that is supplied from Stitch and handle the fields in that collection? Seems like I would be duplicating the User data, but I'm not sure I understand another way to do it. Still learning, I appreciate any feedback/advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to store your own data on the internal user objects. Instead, you can use authentication triggers to manage users. The following snippet is taken from these [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/trigger-snippets/#store-new-users-in-mongodb).

```
exports = function(authEvent){
   // Only run if this event is for a newly created user.
   if (authEvent.operationType !== "CREATE") { return }

   // Get the internal `user` document
   const { user } = authEvent;

   const users = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas")
       .db("myApplication")
       .collection("users");

   const isLinkedUser = user.identities.length > 1;

   if (isLinkedUser) {
        const { identities } = user;
        return users.updateOne(
            { id: user.id },
            { $set: { identities } }
        )

    } else {
        return users.insertOne({ _id: user.id, ...user })
             .catch(console.error)
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, totally missed that part in the documentation. Sounds like creating a Users collection is the way to go and create Stitch functions to fire off.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB innovates at a very fast pace - and while in 2019 there wasn't a way to do this elegantly, now there is. You can now enable custom user data on MongoDB realm! (https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/users/enable-custom-user-data/)

https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/node/advanced/access-custom-user-data

```
const user = context.user;
user.custom_data.primaryLanguage == "English";
```

--

```
{
  id: '5f1f216e82df4a7979f9da93',
  type: 'normal',
  custom_data: {
    _id: '5f20d083a37057d55edbdd57',
    userID: '5f1f216e82df4a7979f9da93',
    primaryLanguage: 'English',
  },
  data: { email: 'test@test.com' },
  identities: [
    { id: '5f1f216e82df4a7979f9da90', provider_type: 'local-userpass' }
  ]
}
```

--

```
const customUserData = await user.refreshCustomData()
console.log(customUserData);
```